# command line input and UseShellExecute == true

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd

I have a program that essentially all that is left is to call a command through CMD.exe .

I need to open CMD.exe in my current working directory (i know i can just do Porcess.Start(CMD.exe))

I then need to have the program TYPE a specific string into the cmd.exe. while staying in my current working directory. i cannot use "UseShellExecute == false" as it kills the shell, and i need the shell for it to work.

Apparently i need to be more specific. So, the text that i am trying to write into the cmd.exe is `"clingo.exe \"Constants.txt\" \"Solver.txt\" \"Nodes.txt\" > \"Solved.txt\""`. clingo.exe is an answer set compiler that i am using on the files Constants, Solver and Nodes to get a solution that is piped to Solved. all of these files are in one directory.

Comment: Have you tried `Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "everything else here";`

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you're having trouble using the `Process` class effectively. You'll get better answers, and a better understanding of the problem, if you provide what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm interested in why you think `UseShellExecute=false` won't work for you. Is it possible you're just not using it correctly?

Here's your best option. This will work for 99% of apps:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "clingo.exe",
    Arguments = "\"Constants.txt\" \"Solver.txt\" \"Nodes.txt\"",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

using(Process p = Process.Start(psi))
using(Stream s = File.Create("Solved.txt"))
{
    p.StandardOutput.CopyTo(s);
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Here's an option for the rare app which doesn't like args passed in the standard way, but works with cmd.exe:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false // note this applies to cmd.exe specifically,
                            // NOT the processes that you start from cmd.exe
};

using(Process p = Process.Start(psi))
{
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("clingo \"Constants.txt\" \"Solver.txt\" \"Nodes.txt\" > \"Solved.txt\"");
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

You may need to redirect StandardOutput and StandardError as well for this one to work -- I forget!

Comment: i agree i was doing something wrong.. what you had before worked just fine.. the problem i assume was i was thinking that it would just RUN just like i had opened cmd.exe manually and typed it manually and when i hit enter manually.. i did not realize i needed to grad stantard out and do operations on it. it is now working 100% with what you had before

Comment: Glad to hear it! `Process.Start` is a bit more low-level -- cmd.exe is calling something similar to it behind the scenes, but also working some magic of its own here. The `>Solved.txt` bit is not part of the process starting, but is cmd.exe-specific syntax for redirecting standard output of the command on the left of the `>` to the file on the right. When using `Process.Start`, you need to do this yourself.

Comment: yea, it completely makes sense, im just 100% new to system calls from this venue (lots more practice on UNIX machines due to classes. never needed this utility until this. it appears to be working flawlessly which makes me extremely happy and relieved. and i might finally get to bed before 3am=)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to start the process from a command line?  What about this?

```
var process = new Process { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c clingo.exe Constants.txt Solver.txt Nodes.txt") };
process.Start();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.WaitForExit();
//do something with process.StandardOutput, this has the results
```

A few tricks to pay attention to here.  First, use the /c argument to cmd, it will make the prompt exit right away.  Second, depending on your context, you may want to set `process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true`.  Finally, note that redirecting standard output can cause the app to hang if the output exceeds the buffer.  You'll want to make special effort to read that out as it comes in if you expect it to be more than a little bit of data.

Comment: The `> Solved.txt` bit is cmd-script for redirecting clingo's stdout into Solved.txt, so this won't work (but can be easily fixed).

Comment: Also, some rare apps (ImageMagick comes to mind) will for some reason not work with this. For these you actually _do_ need to use cmd.exe, redirecting standard input and writing commands to start the app.

Comment: well as far as i can tell i have to run clingo.exe from cmd.exe for it to work propperly. but i will attempt your answer.

Comment: Whoops, thanks @CoryNelson, fixed that.  Also, changed to use cmd.exe

Comment: I believe that clingo.exe is one of those application.. the problem is that when i turn off the shell, it appears to not actually take any input..

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing argument but make sure your exe argument is correct

```
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = @"C:\clingo.exe \Constants.txt\ \Solver.txt\ \Nodes.txt\ > \Solved.txt\";
proc.Arguments = @"10.2.2.125";
Process.Start(proc);
```

Comment: \clingo.exe \Constants.txt\ \Solver.txt\ \Nodes.txt\ > \Solved.txt\ is actually executes when you enter it in cmd